# Attempting to get popup to appear after register in a form with a getElementId not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have successfully created a popup to display after clicking on a link by using a JavaScript onclick event like this:

However, I am now trying to get figure out how to get this to work without a link needing to be present. I want it to work when a php form is submitted. So basically when someone registers I want a popup to appear after the account has been successfully registered.

I am attempting to do this now like this, but it isn't working at all

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="fullname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('fullname')); ?>" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="inputbarp" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password_again">Confirm password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" class="inputbarp" required>
  </div>


  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
  <label for="signinButton">
    <input id="signinButton" type="submit" value="Register">
  </label><br>
  <onsubmit = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">

    <div id="light" class="signInpopup"><a class="close" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
      <?php $success;?>
    </div>
```

How could I change what I have to get this to work? Also is Ajax a better method for this or should I scrap what I'm trying to do and have it done another way?

Updated Code:

```
<form action="" method="POST"
                                                 onsubmit="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                                                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
                                             return false;">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text"  class="inputbar" name="fullname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('fullname')); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="inputbarp" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="password_again">Confirm password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password_again" class="inputbarp" required>
                        </div>


                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                        <label for="signinButton">
                        <input id="signinButton" type="submit" value="Register">
                        </label><br>

                    <div id="light" class="signInpopup"><a class="close" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
                        <?php $success;?>
                    </div>  

                    </form>
```

Comment: What's `<onsubmit = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">`?

Answer (score 1):

What's `<onsubmit = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">`? It is not valid! Use it this way:

```
<form action="" method="POST"
      onsubmit="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
                return false;">
```

ps: Don't give breaks inside the attribute. This is just for the readability! Use the above code like:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'; return false;">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by giving breaks inside of the atribute? However, this breaks my form and it won't even submit. I want this to show up after the form has been submitted. Then to show my php echo inside of it as the text in the pop up.

Comment: I changed my php to echo the code, but it is still not echoing my variable. I'm guessing it has something to do with the form breaking?

Comment: @Paul, Yes, currently it won't submit the form because we have used `return false;`. You can remove it if you wanna submit it. But once you submit, the whole page goes of, and there's no need of hiding and showing the fade and light right?

Comment: I want the pop up to appear after successfully reloading the page to show a message. Is Ajax my best bet then? If so how would I alter this?

Comment: Yes, AJAX would be the right way. Do a search, I am sure that you can get a lot of results!

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out! Appreciate your help